# Simple Random Redirect is Acting Biased

Tags: javascript, redirect, random

I have a very simple Javascript on a blank redirector page meant to randomly redirect people to 1 of 2 websites.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var urls = new Array("http://www.google.com", "http://www.yahoo.com");
window.location = urls[Math.floor(urls.length*Math.random())];
</script>
```

If a link to this redirector is clicked repeatedly, the odds of landing on either Google or Yahoo seem 50/50. However, when asking lots of people to click it, they seem to overwhelmingly be taken to Yahoo on the first click. Only a couple were taken to Google the first time.

Any clue as to why??

Comment: Javascript is supposed to have a balanced pseudo random number generator. You are correct that therefore (in the large scheme of things) you are supposed to have 50/50 overall outcome. The problem with your question is that anno 2015 there are loads of different browser-vendors and even more versions/patches/updates for each browser, leading to different rng implementations. We can hardly investigate every or even just the current popular implementations. It might however be interesting to ajax back the client browser/OS and first rng number that combo generates on page-load for investigation.

Comment: Also, loads of implementations use the OS's underlying prng.. (noting that the (legacy) windows prng is _notoriously_ crappy/predictable).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ECMAScript/javascript defines `Math.random()` as:

> Returns a Number value with positive sign, greater than or equal to 0
>   but less than 1, chosen randomly or pseudo randomly with approximately
>   uniform distribution over that range, using an
>   implementation-dependent algorithm or strategy. This function takes no
>   arguments.

In order to guarantee that there is an 'approximately uniform distribution', one obviously needs a well-known mathematical algorithm (and there are quite some of them). Hence, the resulting (depending on algorithm infinite) sequence's distribution correlates to the sample-size.

So, you are correct that in the long haul... you'll get pretty close to 50/50 distribution **on the same host during the same session!**

...which are the first 2 things that are biasing your test-result and their interpretation:

- the scale of your test (you'd need at the *very* least 1000 samples of each OS/Browser/Host combo)
- these tests were executed on *different* OS/Browser/Host combos (so different sequences on different positions)

That means, that you (the receiver of a *sequence of testresults*) obtained something that very closely approaches true randomness.. for which a uniform distribution can only be sown in a huge to infinite sample-size!

Obligatory Dilbert:
[image: Dilbert random]
<sup>Source: http://dilbert.com/strip/2001-10-25</sup>

Now, if you are saying you have got a large set testresults in which you have found a significant bias towards a specific OS/Browser/Host combo where there is a clear bias towards `Math.random` returning a value above `0.5` as first value after your page/app has loaded, then please share/prove that information (which browser(-version) on which OS..?? That would be interesting and in fact the only thing one can seriously further investigate)!!!

---

I have included some test-demo's below (note the output textarea *pre*-pends output):

1. The first button clears the output textarea.
2. The second button prints 20 random (50/50) results.
   Click it a number of times and note that you are looking at a string of yes/no (0/1) divided in groups of 20..  If you had divided the same results in another quantity every line could start with a different value..
   Also note how you'll see strings of repeating values (like the Dilbert cartoon) and something that (on a small sample scale) appears to be more alternating.
3. The third button ramps this up and shows the approximately uniform distribution (total of each each no and yes) over a sample-size you can select (don't make it *to* big..)
   Again, click it a number of times, get a 'feel'. See how a small scale (like 10) can give a large percentual difference, but as you ramp up the samples you should see 50/50 or a close (percentual) match!
4. Now, the forth button is interesting and explores your idea (that you commented on another erroneous answer) of better utilizing random's resolution: increasing the data-set by adding duplicates of the existing dataset.

   Changing `["http://www.google.com", "http://www.yahoo.com"]` aka `[0,1]` to `[0,1,0,1]` is simply your dataset repeated or multiplied (because `[0,1,0]` would have a clear bias towards `0`).  So, factor 1 is the bare dataset `[0,1]`, factor 2 is `[0,1,0,1]`, etc.
   Without increasing the dataset but just calculating the equivalent we can get the same behavior: `floor( (array.length * factor) * random ) % array.length`

   > **PLOT on WolframAlpha:** [`plot floor((x*f)*r)mod x where x=2, f=4 for r=0 to 0.99999`](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+floor%28%28x*f%29*r%29mod+x+where+x%3D2%2C+f%3D4+for+r%3D0+to+0.99999)
   >   Were: `x=number of items` (aka array.length) and `f=factor`.
   >   Note that it is interesting to play with `round` or `ceil` showing *why* `floor` gives the best distribution. Also play with `x` and `f` to *see* why this works.

   Clicking the button shows 10 random values (shrunk to the first 3 chars, so 1 decimal digit), followed by the results of the first 5 factors (as a table).
   Click it a number of times and see how every factor can still get Dilbert-like repetition or short-scale alternations. See how no of the factors (in the example) give a reasonable improvement: pick a 'favorite' factor, click the button a number of times and see if it is still your 'favorite', pick a new 'favorite', rinse and repeat..
5. The fifth button shows the distribution (like the second button) for factor 2.  Note that the results (depending on sample-size) are in line with what we (should) see with the forth button.
6. The sixth button shows the distribution for a x-amount of samples for an actual data set you can multiply/factorize and even randomize..
   (note: enter only `0` or `1`, separated with `,` (spaces and tabs are ignored))
   It is interesting to toy with this. Randomizing ORDER combined with the approximately uniform distribution of javascript's random still shouldn't notably bias results.

```html
<textarea id="outp" style="width:98%;height:200px;"></textarea>

<button onclick="
  document.getElementById('outp').value='';
">clear output
</button>

<br />

<button onclick="
  var res= []
  ,   rnd= Math.random
  , floor= Math.floor
  ,  outp= document.getElementById('outp')
  ,     i= 20
  ;
  while(i--) res.push(  floor( rnd()*2 )  );
  outp.value= res + '\n' + outp.value;
">show 20 50/50 randoms
</button>

<br />

<button onclick="
  var res= [0,0]
  ,   rnd= Math.random
  , floor= Math.floor
  ,  outp= document.getElementById('outp')
  ,     i= Number(this.nextSibling.value) || 100000
  ;
  while(i--) ++res[  floor( rnd()*2 )  ];
  outp.value= res + '\n' + outp.value;
">sample 50/50 distribution for:
</button><input type="text" value="1000000" /> samples (try 10, 100, 1000 etc.)


<br />

<button onclick="
  var resT= []
  ,   resA= []
  ,   resB= []
  ,   resC= []
  ,   resD= []
  ,   resE= []
  ,    rnd= Math.random
  ,  floor= Math.floor
  ,   outp= document.getElementById('outp')
  ,      i= 10
  ,      t
  ;
  while(i--){
    t=rnd();
    resT.push(  t.toString().slice(0,3)  );
    resA.push(  floor( t* 2 )    );
    resB.push(  floor( t* 4 )%2  );
    resC.push(  floor( t* 6 )%2  );
    resD.push(  floor( t* 8 )%2  );
    resE.push(  floor( t*10 )%2  );
  }
  outp.value= 'rnd '    + resT.join('  ')
            + '\nf1:  ' + resA.join('    ')
            + '\nf2:  ' + resB.join('    ')
            + '\nf3:  ' + resC.join('    ')
            + '\nf4:  ' + resD.join('    ')
            + '\nf5:  ' + resE.join('    ')
            + '\n\n' + outp.value;
">show 10 50/50 randoms + 'improved' resolution factor f1-f5
</button>

<br />

<button onclick="
  var res= [0,0]
  ,   rnd= Math.random
  , floor= Math.floor
  ,  outp= document.getElementById('outp')
  ,     i= Number(this.nextSibling.value) || 100000
  ;
  while(i--) ++res[  floor( rnd()*4 )%2  ];
  outp.value= res + '\n' + outp.value;
">sample 50/50 distribution f2 for:
</button><input type="text" value="1000000" /> samples (try 10, 100, 1000 etc.)

<br /><br />

<button onclick="
  var res= [0,0]
  ,   rnd= Math.random
  , floor= Math.floor
  ,  outp= document.getElementById('outp')
  ,   dat= document.getElementById('data_set').value
                   .replace(/\s/g,'').split(',')
  ,     L= dat.length
  ,     i= Number(this.nextSibling.value) || 100000
  ;
  while(i--) ++res[  +dat[floor( rnd()*L )]  ];
  outp.value= res + '\n' + outp.value;
">sample 50/50 distribution for factorised (suffled) data-set for:
</button><input type="text" value="1000000" /> samples <br />for dataset:
<input type="text" id="data_set" value="0,1 , 0,0 , 0,0 , 1,1 , 1,1" />
```

Running snippet in full-screen is recommended.